Unable to access child elements of parsed unescaped XML in XSLT Processor 3.0
Using Saxon-HE 10.9 with XSLT 3.0, I am trying to convert unescaped XML string embedded in a larger XML file. I have accomplished this by using
   <xsl:template match="INTERNAL_MATCH" mode="dataset">
      <xsl:variable name="unescapedXML" select="parse-xml(.)"/>
      <TESTVAL>
         <xsl:element name="output-params2">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//$unescapedXML" />
         </xsl:element>
      </TESTVAL> 
   </xsl:template>


and the output reads as such:
        <TESTVAL>
            <output-params2>
               <product ism:ownerProducer="USA">
                  <name>Test Product</name>
                  <shortName>TP</shortName>
                  <base type="testtype" id="1235"/>
                  <base type="testtype2" id="1236"/>
               </product>
            </output-params2>
        </TESTVAL>

However, I want to access the child nodes of this output instead to be able to parse the base elements by their type, if type = 'testtype' then store it's id as variable.
How would I accomplish this? I tried doing accessor
<xsl:copy-of select="//$unescapedXML/product/base" />

But it returns nothing.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Just access it like any other XPath variable: $unescapedXML/product/base

It is not clear how your XML looks, are there any namespaces declared? The product ism:ownerProducer="USA" suggests there is at least a namespace binding for ism. Is there perhaps a default namespace declaration <product xmlns="http://example.org" ..>, too?

The <xsl:copy-of select="//$unescapedXML/product/base" /> should be simplified to <xsl:copy-of select="$unescapedXML/product/base" />, as @Fravadona already pointed out. But it might there is a default namespace declaration in the sample so your path doesn't work, declare e.g. <xsl:copy-of select="$unescapedXML/product/base" xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com"/>, where the http://example.com should say whatever the default namespace from the XML says. Or try <xsl:copy-of select="$unescapedXML/*:product/*:base" /> to work against any namespace.

The // prefix on your xsl:copy-of/@select expression doesn't belong there.


parse the base elements by their type, if type = 'testtype' then store it's id

Given the following input:
XML
<INTERNAL_MATCH>&lt;product ownerProducer="USA"&gt;&lt;name&gt;Test Product&lt;/name&gt;&lt;shortName&gt;TP&lt;/shortName&gt;&lt;base type="testtype" id="1235"/&gt;&lt;base type="testtype2" id="1236"/&gt;&lt;/product&gt;</INTERNAL_MATCH>

this stylesheet:
XSLT 3.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="INTERNAL_MATCH">
    <xsl:variable name="unescapedXML" select="parse-xml(.)"/>
    <TESTVAL>
        <output-params2>
            <xsl:value-of select="$unescapedXML/product/base[@type='testtype']/@id" />
         </output-params2>
      </TESTVAL> 
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

will return:
Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TESTVAL>
   <output-params2>1235</output-params2>
</TESTVAL>

Important:
I have removed the undeclared namespace prefix ism: from your input example. I assume that in your real input this prefix is properly declared and bound to a namespace, otherwise you would get an error instead of the result you report.
In addition, as noted in the comments to your question, it is quite possible that your real input contains another namespace declaration that puts the product and/or base elements in a namespace of their own. In such case your stylesheet must take this into account - see here how.

Thanks this is helpful, marking as anwer! It was the namespace that was an issue for me, apologies for not providing enough information, it's for a somewhat sensitive use and so I was trying to put as little as possible.
Basically I had confused a namespace with an element, and so I was not referencing it properly when trying to XPath it. Learning the basics... whoops.
